# How to protect part of a cakephp website for a stage deployment?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cakephp, basic-authentication

I have a cakephp project consisting of website URLs and a URL for an API, say:

- http://myproject.com/controller1/someaction
- http://myproject.com/controller2/someotheraction
- http://myproject.com/api/controller1/someapiaction

For production deployment, the websites and API both handle authentication & authorization using cakephp's methods.

I would like to deploy the whole project on a staging server. There, the websites should be HTTP Auth protected, whilst the API should be unprotected (because I don't want to add auth to the API consumers). I do not want to change the project's sources or configuration and instead solve it via Apache configuration.

I tried several vhost configurations, basically following this scheme:

```
   <LocationMatch "/api/.*">
           Order allow,deny
           Allow from all
           Satisfy any
   </LocationMatch>

   <Location />
           Order allow,deny
           Allow from all
           AllowOverride all

           AuthType Basic
           AuthName "myproject"
           AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
           AuthGroupFile /path/to/.htgroup
           Require group mytesters
   </Location>
```

I also tried mixing Location & Directory directives, using Location or LocationMatch for both sections, negated regex for LocationMatch, separate vhosts for both sections, ... - none of this worked: Either the whole site was protected, or nothing.

Am I getting something really wrong, or is it just not possible (due to Apache or the the way cakephp handles rewrites)?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following configuration:

```
<Directory /path/to/your/htdocs>
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "myproject"
    AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
    AuthGroupFile /path/to/.htgroup
    Require valid-user

    AllowOverride AuthConfig
</Directory>

<Location "/api">
    Satisfy any
</Location>
```

Comment: Doesn't work, it's still requesting auth for /api. Plus, the rewrite rules cakephp uses require an additional AllowOverride FileInfo Options.